# Differences when using functions for casper.evaluate

Tags: javascript, function, casperjs

I'm using PhantomJS v2.0 and CasperJS 1.1.0-beta3. I want to query a specific part inside the page DOM.

Here the code that did not work:

```
function myfunc()
{
    return document.querySelector('span[style="color:#50aa50;"]').innerText;    
}
var del=this.evaluate(myfunc());

this.echo("value: " + del);
```

And here the code that did work:

```
var del=this.evaluate(function() 
{
   return document.querySelector('span[style="color:#50aa50;"]').innerText; 
});

this.echo("value: " + del);
```

It seems to be the same, but it works different, I don't understand.

And here a code that did also work:

```
function myfunc()
{
    return document.querySelector('span[style="color:#50aa50;"]').innerText;    
}
var del=this.evaluate(myfunc);

this.echo("value: " + del);
```

The difference here, I call the myfunc without the '()'.

Can anyone explain the reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is this:

```
var text = this.evaluate(myfunc());
```

Functions in JavaScript are first class citizen. You can pass them into other functions. But that's not what you are doing here. You call the function and pass the result into evaluate, but the result is not a function.

Also `casper.evaluate()` is the page context, and only the page context has access to the document. When you call the function (with `()`) essentially **before** executing `casper.evaluate()`, you erroneously try to access the document, when it is not possible.

The difference to `casper.evaluate(function(){...});` is that the anonymous function is defined and passed into the `evaluate()` function.

There are cases where a function should be called instead of passed. For example when currying is done, but this is not applicable to `casper.evaluate()`, because it is sandboxed and the function that is finally run in `casper.evaluate()` cannot use variables from outside. It must be self contained. So the following code will also **not work**:

```
function myFunc2(a){
    return function(){
        // a is from outer scope so it will be inaccessible in `evaluate`
        return a;
    };
}
casper.echo(casper.evaluate(myFunc2("asd"))); // null
```

You should use

```
var text = this.evaluate(myfunc);
```

to pass a previously defined function to run in the page context.

It's also not a good idea to use reserved keywords like `del` as variable names.

Comment: Ah thanks for your good explanation.
That means, when I write `myfunc` without the `()` then the function will not be called before the evaluate will be called. Instead the `myfunc`will be handled as like a variable and will be passed as an argument to the evaluate function. With the effect the `myfunc`will be called after the evaluate will be called ? Right ?

Comment: `evaluate` *uses* the function that is passed in, so you cannot say that the function is executed after evaluate finished. If you want to know how it uses it, you can look into the source code of PhantomJS. The `evaluate` argument is not used as a callback when the execution is finished. It is a function to tell evaluate what to do.